# What comes into calculation of certificate signature?

Tags: certificates, openssl

I have written my own code with openssl in order to create certificates. In order to verify this code, I tried to reconstruct an openssl commandline generated self-signed certificate ...

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -new -out test.pem -key privateKey.pem -config ./caconfig.cnf
```

... with my code, including startdate, enddate, serial, etc.

```
X509* tempX509=X509_new();
X509_set_version(tempX509,0); /* set to X509 version 1 */
ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(tempX509), serialTmp);
//X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(tempX509), 0);
//X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(tempX509), 60*60*24*daysTmp);
ASN1_TIME_set_string( X509_get_notBefore(tempX509), "YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZ");
ASN1_TIME_set_string( X509_get_notAfter(tempX509), "YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZ");
X509_set_pubkey(tempX509,pubkeyTemp);

X509_NAME *x509_name = NULL;
x509_name = X509_get_subject_name(tempX509);    

if( strlen(countryTmp) )
  if(!(X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(x509_name, "C",  MBSTRING_ASC, (TDF_UCHAR*)countryTmp, -1, -1, 0)))
    return K_TDF_STATUS_CERT_ADD_ERROR;

if( strlen(stateTmp) )
  if(!(X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(x509_name, "ST",  MBSTRING_ASC, (TDF_UCHAR*)stateTmp, -1, -1, 0)))
    return K_TDF_STATUS_CERT_ADD_ERROR;

if( strlen(localityTmp) )
  if(!(X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(x509_name, "L",  MBSTRING_ASC, (TDF_UCHAR*)localityTmp, -1, -1, 0)))
    return K_TDF_STATUS_CERT_ADD_ERROR;

if( strlen(organizationTmp) )
  if(!(X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(x509_name, "O",  MBSTRING_ASC, (TDF_UCHAR*)organizationTmp, -1, -1, 0)))
    return K_TDF_STATUS_CERT_ADD_ERROR;

if( strlen(organizationUnitTmp) )
  if(!(X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(x509_name, "OU",  MBSTRING_ASC, (TDF_UCHAR*)organizationUnitTmp, -1, -1, 0)))
    return K_TDF_STATUS_CERT_ADD_ERROR;

if( strlen(commonNameTmp) )
  if(!(X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(x509_name, "CN", MBSTRING_ASC, (TDF_UCHAR*)commonNameTmp,   -1, -1, 0)))
    return K_TDF_STATUS_CERT_ADD_ERROR;

if( strlen(emailAddressTmp) )
  if(!(X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(x509_name, "emailAddress", MBSTRING_ASC, (TDF_UCHAR*)emailAddressTmp,   -1, -1, 0)))
    return K_TDF_STATUS_CERT_ADD_ERROR; 

if(!(X509_set_issuer_name(tempX509, x509_name)))
  return K_TDF_STATUS_CERT_GEN_ERROR;

if(!X509_sign( tempX509, privkeyTemp, getDigestType(engine)))
  return K_TDF_STATUS_CERT_GEN_ERROR;
```

Unfortunately, the signature is not the same, although all other data seems to be the same. checked by

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in test.pem
```

My code is based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256405/programmatically-create-x509-certificate-using-openssl

So, I wonder whether I forgot something for my certificate creation. How is the signature calculated?

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually doing. Are you using `openssl-lib` to call to openssl functions? are you trying to rewrite openssl's algorithm to sign a certificate ? In the former case, a summary of the used functions with parameters could help, in the latter case I would advise you to refer to the association RFC5280.

Comment: I'm using the lib. In fact my code resembles this post from the link above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15082282/6193352

Comment: Signatures of the same payload are not supposed to be identical bitwise. (A random ingredient goes into it AFAIK.) But the signatures should be valid.